# grails url mapping

Tags: url, grails, mapping

i am new to grails & want to know:-
how to get the default grails url mapping in grails? Where are they stored? how can the default url mappings replaced by our custom url mappings from the grails controller?

Answer (score 1):

URLMapping is done in the urlmappings.groovy file. Read more on how to map on http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.4%20URL%20Mappings

Comment: Link not working... This is the reason why you don't put only links without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of UrlMappings

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

See the latest documentation: 
https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/URL%20mappings.html